# Generics problem

Tags: c#, generics

I'm making a class so I can cheat at minesweeper, and is currently building up some generics... but I'm kinda stuck. I want to return a int but how do i convert it?

```
public T ReadMemory<T>(uint adr)
{
    if( address != int.MinValue )
        if( typeof(T) == typeof(int) )
            return Convert.ChangeType(MemoryReader.ReadInt(adr), typeof(T));
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown read type");
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use generics, if you want to always use an int?

Comment: Why are you using a uint as a pointer instead of the type specifically designed for that, UIntPtr ? Or, for that matter, why not use *a pointer to int*?

Comment: Why are there two variables, one called "address" and one called "adr"? are they meant to be the same? What's the difference between them?

Comment: And if you want to read an int from an unmanaged memory location without using unsafe code, then why aren't you simply calling Marshal.ReadInt32?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast the return value from the call to `ChangeType`

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(MemoryReader.ReadInt(adr), typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting:

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(MemoryReader.ReadInt(adr), typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to fix the compiler errors. But I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for.

You have to cast the result to T

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType( MemoryReader.ReadInt( adr ), typeof( T ) );
```

and you have to return a value when the conditions fail:

```
return default( T );
```

This results in:

```
public T ReadMemory<T>( uint adr )
{
    if ( adr != int.MinValue )
    {
        if ( typeof( T ) == typeof( int ) )
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType( MemoryReader.ReadInt( adr ), typeof( T ) );
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( "Unknown read type" );
        }
    }
    return default( T );
}
```